# Vulnerability in /boaform/admin/formLogin?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hacking, post, http-server

I am getting this HTTP request line on my server (simple http server). The normal action for this request on my server is to simply close the socket connection. I am asking this question because when I web search `what is /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.1`, it gives me some vulnerability. Is there anything I need to do if I am getting this request but my server is just closing the connection?

```
POST /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.1
```

Is this an active zero-day exploit? I don't know what it means.

Comment: "...but my server is just closing the connection" - that would seem to be the best response.

Comment: They are fishing, likely sequentially through IP addresses, hoping to find a router that has that exploit open.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be related to a [cluster of exploits that target fiber optic routers](https://www.theregister.com/2020/04/16/fiber_routers_under_fire/). If you are running a simple HTTP website and you are not maintaining fiber optic router equipment, I believe you can ignore those requests.